# Conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}(X_1 | \max \{X_1,...,X_n\})$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

few days ago i asked similar thing about conditional expectation and at first leonbloy's and Eupraxis's solutions seemed logical to me. Right now i can't explain myself following problem:

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d $U([0,1])$. And $Z:=\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$.

Then i understand that $\mathbb{P}(X_1=z|Z=z)=\frac{1}{n}$. Since $\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq z|Z=z)=1$ it follows that 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_1 < z|Z=z)=\frac{n-1}{n}.
\end{align*}

But i was told before $X_1$ conditioned being less than $Z=z$ has $U([0,z))$ distribution. Does it not imply that $\mathbb{P}(X_1 <a |Z=z)=\frac{a}{z-0}$ i.e $\mathbb{P}(X_1 <z|Z=z)=\frac{z}{z-0}=1$?

Something is definetly wrong, but what did i misunderstand?

The cdf in my case is probably:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq t|Z=z)=
\begin{cases} 
   0 & \text{ if } t\leq0 \\
   \frac{t(n-1)}{zn} & \text{ if } 0 < t <z \\
   1 &  \text{ elsewhere}
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Your $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt z|Z=z)=\frac{n-1}{n}$ looks correct.

Your $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt a |Z=z)=\frac{a}{z-0}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt z|Z=z)=\frac{z}{z-0}=1$ are in fact conditional probabilities and might be rewritten as: $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt a |Z=z \land X_1 \lt z )=\frac{a}{z}$$ $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt z|Z=z  \land X_1 \lt z)=1$$ or, taking account of $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt z|Z=z)=\frac{n-1}{n}$, as: $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt a \le z |Z=z )=\frac{(n-1)a}{nz}$$ $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt z|Z=z  )=\frac{n-1}{n}.$$

Your cumulative distribution function looks correct. Note that it is discontinuous at $t=z$.

Comment: hey Henry and thx for your time. Sorry but i dont clearly understand what your claim is.
Is $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < z|Z=z)=\frac{z}{z}=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < z|Z=z)=\frac{n-1}{n}$ both correct in your opinion?

Comment: No: $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < z|Z=z)\not= 1$.  It would only be $1$ conditioned on $X_1$ not being the maximum at which point you reach the tautology $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < z|X_1 < z)= 1$

Answer (score 0):

This is basically equivalent to Henry's answer.

Let $E$ be the event $X_1=Z$.

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt a \mid Z=z)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 <a \land E \mid  Z=z)+\mathbb{P}(X_1 <a \land E^c \mid  Z=z)$$

For $0<a \le z$ the first term is zero, so

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbb{P}(X_1 \lt a \mid Z=z)&=&\mathbb{P}(X_1 <a \land E^c \mid  Z=z)\\
&=&\mathbb{P}(X_1 <a \mid  Z=z \land E^c ) \, \mathbb{P}(E^c\mid Z=z) \\
&=&\frac{a}{z} \frac{n-1}{n}
\end{array}
$$

You are wrongly assuming that $\mathbb{P}(X_1 <a \mid  Z=z)$, when $a<z$, should equal  $\mathbb{P}(X_1 <a \mid  Z=z \land E^c )$, but this is not true.

Comment: awesome leonbloy, your plays with $E$ solved the understanding problem. 
It would be really great if you could edit your post with explaination (your understanding) or maybe even real mathematical proof why 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_1 < a| Z=z, X_1 < z)
\end{align*} has $U([0,z])$ distribution. I can imagene this to be true and can somehow explain it to myself but not with a 100% clear mathematical proof.